# Double Home button press does not work in iOS Simulator

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, xcode8

If I try to display the multitasking menu with keyboard gestures in iOS Simulator 10.3 bundled with Xcode 8.3, it fails to respond; hovever, the single button press and the option from the menu still works. What can I do to get it to work again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you disconnect the hardware keyboard (<kbd>⌘⌥K</kbd>), it starts working again. This seems to be a bug with iOS Simulator 10.3.

Comment: This did not make a difference

Comment: @Tamás thanks that really did work. It's August and this issue still there.
I didn't remove the keyboard. Just hold `⌘⌥`, tap once `K` and tap twice `H` did the trick!

Comment: Thanks... Lucky I came across this answer! was hitting ⌘+shift+H all day :)