# iOS simulator: double click home button does not work sometimes

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, home-button

With the iOS simulator version 10, double clicking the home button to bring up multitasking (running apps) sometimes does not respond. Even hitting (cmd + shift + h)x2 to simulate home button double click also works sometimes. I have verified this with a work mate and they have the same issue. I am not sure if this is a bug in the simulator or if there is a setting somewhere on for example the delay between the clicks? The answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43232769/double-home-button-press-does-not-work-in-ios-simulator) did not make a difference.

Comment: For the iPad, I have resorted to swiping up from close to the bottom to the centre of the screen to bring up multitasking. A workaround on the iPad for now.

Comment: This constantly happens and they've never fixed it

Comment: This is a long-lasting bug. Regardless of whether you use the shortcut, touchbar button or the home button, it just works sporadically.

Comment: Bug still happening. Xcode 11.3.1.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have this problem too when I want to close my app. So, I use command line instead:

```
xcrun simctl list | grep Booted
```

then copy simulator ID, and run this command to close app

```
xcrun simctl terminate <simulator ID> <your app bundle ID>
```

... or if you have **only one simulator running**, just type `booted`:

```
xcrun simctl terminate booted <your app bundle ID>
```

Comment: I will certainly try this

Comment: I'm marking this as the correct answer for now, as there seems to be no way to fix the issue.

Comment: I've made such script that contains all my app bundle IDs and some apple apps like Safari and Preferences — very useful, now I have just one click for closing all apps in the simulator.

Comment: maybe this is too outdated but sadly, trashy simulator STILL has this BUG. Shame on apple that doesn't fix this and a ton of other bugs.

No need to restart simulator. 

TRY THIS: leave ctrl-cmd-H pressed and eventually you'll see App Switcher showing but you have to be quick releasing the keys or App Switcher will disappear and go to Home.

Answer (score 3):

Enable this setting in the simulator hardware settings.

> Hardware > Keyboard > **Send Keyboard Shortcuts to Device**

Command + Shift + H + H will no longer do anything BUT double tapping the home button on the simulator will start working as expected.

Comment: I tried this but the keyboard shortcut still only works about 50% of the time.

Comment: Didn't work. It works as badly as clicking the home button twice.

Comment: Instead of Command + Shift + H + H, try Shift + Command + H + H. I found out that the order matters